# WPF Task.Run ==> Thread Cannot Access This Object

Tags: c#, task, invoke, dispatcher

I have 3 usercontrols in my Main Form and i created all usercontrols in Ctor Main Form The problem is i use Task.Run in Ctor Monitoring and it's working just fine , but when i change usercontrol(Page) and  come back to Monitoring Page, task.run in Ctor Monitoring is not working but When i Use Dispatcher.Invoke all codes are working fine But Ui is freezing.

Main Form:
        // Pages
        PageHome ph;
        PageMonitoring pm;
        PageAboutus pa;

```
    public FrmMain(string userName, string password)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HomeLoadOfflineHelper.HomeLoadOffline(userName, password);

        txbUserName = userName;

        ph = new PageHome(userName, password);
        pm = new PageMonitoring();
        pa = new PageAboutus();

        DataContext = this;
    }
```

Monitoring ctor:

```
    public PageMonitoring()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeNetworkInterface();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {

            short Counter = 0;

            LessPingSeries = new ChartValues<ObservableValue> { };
            NormalPingSeries = new ChartValues<ObservableValue> { };
            DownloadSeries = new ChartValues<ObservableValue> { };
            UploadSeries = new ChartValues<ObservableValue> { };

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                MessageBox.Show("OK");

                using (Ping ping = new Ping())
                {
                    LessPingSeries.Add(new ObservableValue(ping.Send("8.8.8.8").RoundtripTime));
                    NormalPingSeries.Add(new ObservableValue(ping.Send("4.2.2.4").RoundtripTime));
                }

                DownloadSeries.Add(new ObservableValue(ByteSize.FromBytes(bytesReceivedSpeed).MegaBytes));
                UploadSeries.Add(new ObservableValue(ByteSize.FromBytes(bytesSentSpeed).MegaBytes));

                Counter++;
                if (Counter >= 5)
                {
                    LessPingSeries.RemoveAt(0);
                    NormalPingSeries.RemoveAt(0);

                    DownloadSeries.RemoveAt(0);
                    UploadSeries.RemoveAt(0);

                    Counter--;
                }

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    UpdateNetworkInterface();
                });
            }
        });

        DataContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: You only need to invoke the lines of code which actually accesses the ui controls.

Comment: You probably want to assign the `LessPingSeries = new ChartValues<ObservableValue> { };` (and others) in the constructor, not in the task.

Comment: When I Use Invoke My Ui is Freeze , if you see in Code I using Dispatcher.Invoke For Small Method

Comment: Also, who is accessing the `LessPingSeries` fields? if the UI uses them to bind them to a control, you're getting problems, because the task is also accessing them. You should cache the values first and pass them to the Dispatcher.Invoke and add them there to the right ChartValues. It doesn't fix your UI Freeze, but it should be fixed. What is your UpdateNetworkInterface doing? Can you show us it?